# Floor property In general, ⌊ n x ⌋ = n ⌊ x ⌋ .

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am trying to proof the above statement. I have concluded this statement is true if x and n is an integer and real. For example if I take n=3 and x =2 then ⌊ 3. 2 ⌋ = 3 ⌊ 2 ⌋ which is ⌊6⌋ = (3 . 2)  which is 6=6 which proves the statement. But how do I prove this statement without taking n=3 or n=4 etc . ? Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand.  If you are saying that both $x$ and $n$ are integers, it is trivial.  If you are allowing $x$ to be non-integer then $\lfloor 3\cdot \frac{1}{3}\rfloor\neq 3\cdot \lfloor \frac{1}{3}\rfloor$.  If you are allowing $n$ to be a non-integer then $\lfloor \frac{1}{3}\cdot 4\rfloor \neq \frac{1}{3}\lfloor 4\rfloor$

Comment: $\lfloor 2 \times \frac{2}{3} \rfloor \neq 2 \times\lfloor  \frac{2}{3} \rfloor$.

Comment: who is MonicaC @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: @SomeGuy: It's a complicated story, but in brief she's a moderator who many feel was treated very badly by StackExchange. You can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it) as a start if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=3$ and $x=\frac{1}{3}$

floor(NX)= floor(1) = 1 $\neq$ 0 = 3(0) = 3 (floor($\frac{1}{3}$)) = N*floor(X).

Comment: I meant to say if x is an integer then statement is true

Comment: I didn't know. ..

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $N$, we have $floor(N)=N$. Also if $x$ and $n$ are integers $nx$ is an integer, since integers are closed with respect to multiplication. So $$floor(nx) = nx = n(x) = n (floor(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, this property does not hold for an integer $x$ and a real number $n$. For example, If I chose $x=2$ and $n=0.6$, I would have $n \lfloor x \rfloor$ = $0.6\lfloor2\rfloor = 1.2$. However, $\lfloor nx \rfloor = \lfloor0.6*2 \rfloor = \lfloor1.2\rfloor = 1$. Thus, this is not true in general.

This property does not hold true for any REAL $x$ and an INTEGER $n$, either. For example, if I chose $x=0.5$ and $n=2$, I would have $n \lfloor x \rfloor$ = $2\lfloor0.5\rfloor = 0$. However, $\lfloor nx \rfloor = \lfloor2*0.5 \rfloor = \lfloor1\rfloor = 1$. Thus, this is not true in general, either.

Comment: He added the hypothesis $x$ is an integer. Don't know if you were in before that. I had a counterexample post up for x is real case but I deleted it.

Comment: Wait you're right, I need to redo my answer

Comment: How is it now  @openproblem